# Out of memory exception while trying to pass an object to a groovy template Play Framework 1.2

Tags: java, garbage-collection, playframework, playframework-1.x

I have this method in controller:

```
public static void show(Long id)
{
    Article article = Article.findById(id);
    //List<Review> reviews = Review.find("byArticle", article).fetch();
    render(article);
}
```

It passes on the article object to template & the template tries to render various fields in the article object.

And then I get outofMemory exception, where am I going wrong ?

This is the error message shown by Play Framework:

```
RuntimeException occured : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Comment: What exact version of the framework are you using? Are you creating a lot of objects in a loop? Are you running with the default jvm memory settings? HAve you tried debugging the application?